# システムを暗号化したArch系OSが自動で暗号化を解除してしまう問題について

Tags: linux, encryption

一身上の都合によりArch系ディトリであるArchLabsのシステムを暗号化して使わざるをえなくなった者です.事の次第を書いていきます.

### なぜ暗号化したのか

完結にまとめますと,ラップトップを紛失した際や,万が一犯罪に巻き込まれてしまった時のために暗号化しました.もちろんプライバシー保護を強固なものにするという理由でもあります.

### 本題

システムを暗号化したものの,何故かOSの読み込み(ログインではない)と同時に暗号化が自動で解除されてしまいます.本来であれば,システム起動時にパスフレーズを求められるはずですが,なぜかそれがありませんでした.調べてみてもよくわからず,どうもキーファイルを自動で読み込んでいるのではないか(暗号化する際に英語で"キーファイルが..."と出たので)と想像していますが,根本的な解決には至りませんでした.

### 参考にしたサイト

暗号化の方法は[こちら](http://u10e10.hatenablog.com/entry/dm-crypt-usage)の方法で暗号化しました,ただ暗号化方式はAESではなくCamelliaに変更し,システムのインストールとロケーション設定や領域のフォーマット・ディレクトリの割当には専用のインストーラーである`archlabs-installer`を使いました.

なお,GRUBに暗号化パーティションを読み込ませる方法は上記のサイトを参考にしました.

### まとめ

まとまりのない文章になりましたが,伺いたいことをまとめると

- システム起動時にパスフレーズを求めてくるように設定するにはどうすればよいのか?
- どこをどのように変更すればよいのか?

なるべく情報を絞り出してみましたが,これぐらいしか書けませんでした.
不明な点等がございましたらコメントの方までお願いします.

### 追記:設定ファイル等の諸設定

GitHubに設定等をまとめたテキストをアップロードしようかと思いましたが,スタックオーバーフローの中で完結した方が得策かと存じ上げますので,こちらに設定等を書かせていただきます.

### /etc/crypttab

特に何も書かれていませんでしたが,念の為こちらに掲載させていただきます.

```
# Configuration for encrypted block devices.
# See crypttab(5) for details.

# NOTE: Do not list your root (/) partition here, it must be set up
#       beforehand by the initramfs (/etc/mkinitcpio.conf).

# <name>       <device>                                     <password>              <options>
# home         UUID=b8ad5c18-f445-495d-9095-c9ec4f9d2f37    /etc/mypassword1
# data1        /dev/sda3                                    /etc/mypassword2
# data2        /dev/sda5                                    /etc/cryptfs.key
# swap         /dev/sdx4                                    /dev/urandom            swap,cipher=aes-cbc-essiv:sha256,size=256
# vol          /dev/sdb7                                    none
```

### /etc/default/grub

```
# GRUB boot loader configuration

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT=5
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="ArchLabs"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="cryptdevice=/dev/sda2:cryptroot"

# Preload both GPT and MBR modules so that they are not missed
GRUB_PRELOAD_MODULES="part_gpt part_msdos"

# Uncomment to enable booting from LUKS encrypted devices
GRUB_ENABLE_CRYPTODISK=y

# Uncomment to enable Hidden Menu, and optionally hide the timeout count
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=5
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true

# Uncomment to use basic console
GRUB_TERMINAL_INPUT=console

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal
#GRUB_TERMINAL_OUTPUT=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
GRUB_GFXMODE=auto

# Uncomment to allow the kernel use the same resolution used by grub
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=keep

# Uncomment if you want GRUB to pass to the Linux kernel the old parameter
# format "root=/dev/xxx" instead of "root=/dev/disk/by-uuid/xxx"
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY=true

# Uncomment and set to the desired menu colors.  Used by normal and wallpaper
# modes only.  Entries specified as foreground/background.
#GRUB_COLOR_NORMAL="light-blue/black"
#GRUB_COLOR_HIGHLIGHT="light-cyan/blue"

# Uncomment one of them for the gfx desired, a image background or a gfxtheme
#GRUB_BACKGROUND="/path/to/wallpaper"
#GRUB_THEME="/path/to/gfxtheme"

# Uncomment to get a beep at GRUB start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"

# Uncomment to make GRUB remember the last selection. This requires to
# set 'GRUB_DEFAULT=saved' above.
#GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT="true"
```

### /etc/mkinitcpio.conf

HOOKSの内容は[このページを参考にしました](http://u10e10.hatenablog.com/entry/dm-crypt-usage)

```
# vim:set ft=sh
# MODULES
# The following modules are loaded before any boot hooks are
# run.  Advanced users may wish to specify all system modules
# in this array.  For instance:
#     MODULES=(piix ide_disk reiserfs)
MODULES=()

# BINARIES
# This setting includes any additional binaries a given user may
# wish into the CPIO image.  This is run last, so it may be used to
# override the actual binaries included by a given hook
# BINARIES are dependency parsed, so you may safely ignore libraries
BINARIES=()

# FILES
# This setting is similar to BINARIES above, however, files are added
# as-is and are not parsed in any way.  This is useful for config files.
FILES=(/crypto_keyfile.bin)

# HOOKS
# This is the most important setting in this file.  The HOOKS control the
# modules and scripts added to the image, and what happens at boot time.
# Order is important, and it is recommended that you do not change the
# order in which HOOKS are added.  Run 'mkinitcpio -H <hook name>' for
# help on a given hook.
# 'base' is _required_ unless you know precisely what you are doing.
# 'udev' is _required_ in order to automatically load modules
# 'filesystems' is _required_ unless you specify your fs modules in MODULES
# Examples:
##   This setup specifies all modules in the MODULES setting above.
##   No raid, lvm2, or encrypted root is needed.
#    HOOKS=(base)
#
##   This setup will autodetect all modules for your system and should
##   work as a sane default
#    HOOKS=(base udev autodetect block encrypt filesystems shutdown)
#
##   This setup will generate a 'full' image which supports most systems.
##   No autodetection is done.
#    HOOKS=(base udev block encrypt filesystems shutdown)
#
##   This setup assembles a pata mdadm array with an encrypted root FS.
##   Note: See 'mkinitcpio -H mdadm' for more information on raid devices.
#    HOOKS=(base udev block mdadm encrypt filesystems)
#
##   This setup loads an lvm2 volume group on a usb device.
#    HOOKS=(base udev block lvm2 filesystems)
#
##   NOTE: If you have /usr on a separate partition, you MUST include the
#    usr, fsck and shutdown hooks.
HOOKS=(base udev autodetect modconf keyboard keymap block encrypt filesystems fsck)
# COMPRESSION
# Use this to compress the initramfs image. By default, gzip compression
# is used. Use 'cat' to create an uncompressed image.
#COMPRESSION="gzip"
#COMPRESSION="bzip2"
#COMPRESSION="lzma"
#COMPRESSION="xz"
#COMPRESSION="lzop"
#COMPRESSION="lz4"

# COMPRESSION_OPTIONS
# Additional options for the compressor
#COMPRESSION_OPTIONS=()
```

Comment: 「一身上の都合」を書かれるよりは、暗号化の手法(=名前)を書いてくれた方が役立つ情報になるかと思います (恐らくは **dm-crypt** )。/ [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.jp/index.php/Dm-crypt)に日本語訳での手順があるので参考に。キーファイルでの自動マウントをしているかは、`/etc/crypttab` ファイルの内容を確認してみるとよいかもしれません。 参考 - [LUKSでファイルシステムを暗号化してみた](https://jehupc.exblog.jp/19078309/)

Comment: すみません,書き忘れていました.暗号化はcryptsetupで行いました.下記に設定等を書きましたので,良ければご覧ください

Comment: 質問とは直接関係が無いのですが、文章を書く際に句読点として半角の`.`や`,`を使うなら、後ろにスペースを入れるべきかと思います。スペースが無いと文字が詰まって表示され非常に読みづらいです。

Comment: アドバイスありがとうございます. 以後気をつけます.

Comment: ルート(/)についてはキーファイルで暗号化して、そのキーファイルを initramfs の /crypto_keyfile.bin に置いているから自動でアンロックされるのではないでしょうか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます. 同様の方法で /etc/mkinitcpio.conf のキーファイルが指定されている箇所をコメントアウトした上で `mkinitcpio -p linux` を実行した結果うまく行きました.

Comment: もし解決した場合には、自己回答として解決に至った内容を投稿してみてください。